# Rotating a 3rd person camera toward a target

Tags: c++, 3d, mathematics, camera, software-engineering

I have a 3rd person camera that doesn't look directly at the player but somewhere in front of him.

When the user enter shooting mode, I want the camera to turn around the player to face the target.

[image: example of what I'm talking about]

In the image above. "O" is the player (Origin), "L" is the lookat, "C" is the camera position and "T" is the target. I want to rotate the lookat line C->L so that it passes by T (C'->L'->T') around the Origin ("O").

Basically I need to find the angle alpha that I put in red in the picture.

I store my camera position in a structure like such :

```
struct CameraTarget {
     Quaternion absoluteRotation;
     Vec3 absolutePosition;
     Vec3 cameraOffset;
     Vec3 lookatOffset;
     float FOV;
}
```

So if I could find the angle I'm looking for I could do something like :

```
cam->absoluteRotation = cam->absoluteRotation * alpha;
```

To get the player to always look at the target.

If the lookat was passing by the Origin I could simply do

```
Vec3 origDir = cam->lookAtOffset - cam->absolutePosition;
origDir.normalize();
Vec3 newDir = cam->target - cam->absolutePosition;
newDir.normalize();
Quaternion q(origDir, newDir); // from->to
cam->absoluteRotation = cam->absoluteRotation * q;
```

However in the diagram above this doesn't quite work since the rotation is offset from the Origin.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself if it helps someone else one day :

SFDKT has the right idea about projecting the target point into the current camera look direction.

However, my biggest problem was finding this point P. Turned out that a bit of trigonometry managed to solve it.

Considering the triangle formed by the three points CPO :

1. Since I know the lengths LO, OC and CL I can calculate the angle at C.
2. Now I know the angle C and the length of OC and PO. Using the law of sines you can find the angle at O. (I found [this website](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-triangles.html) very useful for finding the missing angles)
3. Then I can find the last missing angle P and use again the law of Sines to find the length CP.
4. Take the look direction posC + normalized(CL) * lengthCP gives me the position of P.
5. Once I have P I can calculate the shortest rotation between OP and OT which gives me the quaternion I need to rotate my camera.

I did have a bit of trouble with unwanted roll in 3D but I just solved the problem with Z = 0 then calculated the missing pitch rotation to keep the camera's up vector straight.

Answer (score 0):

this picture adds the symmetry needed to solve the question easier.

[image]

Just project `L` along the vector `CL` so that `|P-O|=|T-O|`.

Now it's obviously just two identical triangles (`CPO` and `C'TO`) rotated by your desired angle.  I.E. `ang(OT)-ang(OP)`

`C'` and `L'` are both the same as `C` and `L` after rotating, about `O`, by the same amount.